# Getting math expression on same line as text

Tags: math-mode, inline

I am trying to write a line on latex with a binomial distribution

```
...is equally likely to be one of the $\begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
n \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\\ m\end{pmatrix}$ graphs with $m$ edges, and for such a distribution $p=\frac{m}{n(n-1)}$.
```

This results in the matrix being bigger than the text.

[image]

How do I get the math expression to the same text size as

[image]

Comment: please try to give relevant tags to a question, it helps future readers find things.

Comment: you should also consider that for inline math you may use backslash parehntesis instead of the dollar symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
...is equally likely to be one of the $\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}$ graphs with $m$ edges, and for such a distribution $p=\frac{m}{n(n-1)}$.

...is equally likely to be one of the $\dbinom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}$ graphs with $m$ edges, and for such a distribution $p=\frac{m}{n(n-1)}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you employ the `smallmatrix` and `psmallmatrix` environments provided by the `mathtools` package. I would also replace the `\frac` expression for `p` with an inline-style fraction expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for smallmatrix and psmallmatrix environments
\begin{document}

\dots is equally likely to be one of the 
$\smash[b]{\Bigl( \!
  \begin{smallmatrix}
    \begin{psmallmatrix} n \\ 2 \end{psmallmatrix} \ 
   m
  \end{smallmatrix}\! \Bigr)}$ 
graphs with $m$ edges, and for such a distribution $p=m/(n(n-1))$.

\end{document}
```