# Writing "lim" on latex

Tags: subscripts, inline

I am trying an inline math expression on latex

```
the graph is almost surely connected ($\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathrm{P}(G(n,p) \text{is connected}) \to 1 $
```

and it outputs the subscript term next to "lim". How do I get it under "lim" like in eqn (6) while using inline.

[image]

Comment: There is a reason why it is typeset as a subscript in i line math. Placing it under disturbs the line spacing too much. Your other line in the image is displayed math and the limit is automatically placed under.

Comment: why have you again tagged this bibtex and biblatex? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657640/getting-math-expression-on-same-line-as-text#comment1638242_657640

Comment: If you absolutely want the subscript under $\lim$, you can code \lim \limits_{n\to\infty}.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]

the graph is almost surely connected ($\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathrm{P}(G(n,p) \text{is connected}) \to 1 $

\lipsum[1][1-2]

the graph is almost surely connected ($\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathrm{P}(G(n,p) \text{is connected}) \to 1 $

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Careful with your 4th example. Putting braces around `\lim\limits...` changes the atom from `\mathop` to `\mathord` and uses the wrong spacing. (Not a big issue _here_ but in general...)

Comment: @campa Thank you. It was my negligence, and it has been corrected.

Comment: Can't upvote again, sorry `;-)`

Comment: @campa That's all right. Thanks again for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my documents I use this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bigints}
\newcommand{\Lim}[1]{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\displaystyle 
\lim_{#1}\;$}}}
\begin{document}
In classical graph thoery the graph is almost surely connected $\left(\Lim{\rightarrow\infty}\operatorname{P}(G(n, p)\text{ is connected})\right)\rightarrow 1$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I could've sworn though I got this from a question here lol, but I can't seem to find it so whatever.